# Parametric equations, eliminating the parameter $\,x = t^2 + t,\,$ $y= 2t-1$

Tags: calculus, parametric

$$x = t^2 + t\qquad y= 2t-1$$

So I solve $y$ for $t$

$$t = \frac{1}{2}(y+1)$$

Then I am supposed to plug it into the equation of $x$ which is where I lose track of the logic.

$$x = \left( \frac{1}{2}(y+1)\right)^2 +  \frac{1}{2}(y+1) = \frac{1}{4}y^2 + y+\frac{3}{4}$$

That is now my answer? I am lost. This is x(y)? How is this valid? I don't understand.

Comment: Answer to what question? You have 2 equations with 3 variables. What is confusing about x(y)?

Comment: But why, I don't understand what is happening.

Comment: @Paul the Pirate:  how is it *not* valid? ;)

Comment: The equation of the parabola was given to you parametrically. Now you have found the "regular" equation for it. Often the parameter cannot be eliminated in any simple way. But in this case it can be, and you did it.

Comment: I know what I did and I know how to memorize and write out the steps but I don't understand why it is valid. I have c(t) = x(y), y(t) and I turn it into y = x. How is this valid?

Comment: A more familiar example is $x=\cos t$, $y=\sin t$, $0\le t\lt 2\pi$. As the parameter $t$ travels over the interval, the pair $(x,y)$ travels over the unit circle. You can eliminate the parameter by calculating $x^2+y^2$.

Comment: Where does x^2 come from?

Comment: You can differentiate $x$ with respect to $u$ and then find $\left(\dfrac{dx}{dy}\right)^{-1}$. Or you could do it through implicit differentiation. Although I'm not too sure what you're particularly asking.

Comment: Your method is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable $t$ in the parametized equations is "the same" $t$: Both $x$ and $y$ are defined in terms of the same variable $t$.

So in solving for $t$ in terms of $y$: $t = \frac 12(y + 1)$, we can use this "definition" of $t$ by substituting it into the equation for $x$: $$x = t^2 + t$$ given $t = \frac 12(y+ 1)$ gives us $$x = \frac 14 y^2 + y + \frac 34$$ as you show.

This then gives us a function of $x$ in terms of $y$: indeed, $x(y) = \frac 14 y^2 + y + \frac 34$ is a "horizontal parabola".

Comment: So I have c(t) = x(t), y(t) then I find c(t) = t(x), y(x) then c(t) just goes away?

Comment: The parametized equations are no longer needed, as all the information contained in them has been translated to, first, information about $t(y)$ then $x(t(y)) \to x(y)$

Comment: It's just like if we had simple equations: $x = t$, $y = t$ $\implies x = y$. Your work uses the same principle, albeit, the route is less direct.

Comment: But where does c(t) go?

Comment: What are you calling $c(t)$? The parametized equations are $x(t), y(t)$. First we find $t = f(y)$. Then we substitute $t = f(y)$ into $x(t)$ which gives us $x(f(y)) = x(y)$. The $x(t), y(t)$ are no longer needed, but the the equation we get in terms of $x, y$ describes the same "function" as do $x(t)$ and $y(t)$, when taken together.

Comment: I guess I just don't understand how that works, how I can go from c(t) = x, y into y = x. I underdtand the steps so i can just memorize those and do them.

Comment: I'll try and figure out a way to explain it better. I'm sorry if I haven't helped any.

Comment: Can I go the other way? Turn a normal function into a parametric?

Comment: Sure you can. When it's useful to do so, and you'll see much more of this the more you get into multivariable calculus. You'll probably encounter such exercises shortly.

Comment: @amWhy: Arg! Nice discourse. :-) +1

Comment: @amWhy: I wish I could solve this one but +.

Answer (score 2):

As $t$ varies through $\mathbb R$, $y$ varies through $\mathbb R$ and $x$ varies too though not through all of $\mathbb R$. The equation you have obtained expresses $x$ in terms of $y$ thus omitting the use of the parameter $t$.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you are walking on an *xy*-plane. Your *x*-position (or east-west position) at a certain time *t* is given by $x = t^2 + t$, and your *y*-position is $y = 2t - 1$.

If you want to know what the whole path you remained is, without wanting to know when you stepped on where? Eliminate *t*:

$$x = \frac{1}{4} y^2 + y + \frac{3}{4}$$

If a pair of $(x, y)$ satisfied that, that means some time in the past or in the future, you stepped or would step on that point.